# Java TSP 2-opt swap

Tags: java

This is my first year with programming at university and we have just started using java. I've already wrote a bunch of codes for calculating "shortest" path through all points, but it has one problem. Sometimes the path will be overlapping each other. I have been looking for 2-opt swap, but have no clue on how to implement this to my code. Would be awesome with help. Here is my code for calculating distances between points ( cities ):

```
    public void calculate(){

    Point current = null;
    current = points.get(0);

    Point nearestPoint = null; 
    ArrayList<Point> remainingPoints = new ArrayList<Point>(points);
    remainingPoints.remove(current);
    lines.clear();

    while(!remainingPoints.isEmpty()){

        double minimumDistance = -1;

        for (int i = 0; i < remainingPoints.size(); i ++){

            if (minimumDistance == - 1 || current.distance(remainingPoints.get(i)) < minimumDistance){

                minimumDistance = current.distance(remainingPoints.get(i));
                nearestPoint = remainingPoints.get(i);
            }

        }

        lines.add(new Point[] { current, nearestPoint });

        remainingPoints.remove(current);
        current = nearestPoint;

    }

    lines.add(new Point[] { points.get(0), current });

}
```

What does it do? Well it is quiet basic. It starts with the first point, then will find the nearest point. This will be saved in an array called lines. This will continue like this until no points are left. Line-array will then be sorted by distances so we can draw lines between them. My question is how can i prevent overlapping? See the links bellow for better description:

[I dont want this](http://gyazo.com/ba981c98bf9592331bb55fc8e0c4b986)

[I want this](http://gyazo.com/f4567e4d0c6292e1210717992a871eb8)